# A grouped cell is showing up in my plain tableView and I don't know why

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uitableview

So I don't know how this is happening, or how to fix it, but I am having an issue of my UISearchDisplayController's **plain** tableView displaying search results with a grouped cell.

I have a dataSource array with a few names, a tableData array that iterates through the dataSource array and adds any entries that fit the searchText, and then depending on which tableView it is, I reload the tableView with the appropriate dataSource...

Ideas anyone?

Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
     int count = 0;

     if(aTableView == self.tableView){
        count = [userTableData count]==0?1:[userTableData count];
     }else{
            count = [tableData count];
     }
     return count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return @"Users"; 
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

if(tView == self.tableView){
    if([userTableData count] == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Please select a user";
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [userTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}else{
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

return cell;

   }
```

And then as the search is entered, matching strings are added to the tableData array

Comment: this code looks good. where have you created the UITable?

Comment: So my viewController is a regular UIViewController subclass, that I am adding a grouped UITableView to. I nest my UISDP atop the grouped tableView, and the UISDP's built-in plain tableView shows up over the grouped one, but just shows a grouped cell...I'd attach an image if I had 10 rep :)

Comment: try hiding the grouped tableview when searching

Comment: I just tried that, and it ended up hiding the tableView (with the attached searchBar), but it still has the grouped border on search results...so weird!

Comment: how do you differentiate between the tableViews ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for `UISearchDisplayController` about the `searchResultsTableView` property, it says

`Discussion:
This method creates a new table view if one does not already exist.`

So what you could try is create your own `UITableView`when you set up the UISDC, explicitly making it plain:

```
UITableView *searchTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero 
    style:UITableViewStylePlain];
searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView = searchTableView;
```

Answer (score 1):

assign tags to the UITableView and hide the grouuped tableView while searching

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but even the tags aren't working correctly. I don't have any idea what could be going on

Comment: can u show code where yu initialize both the tableViews and hiding them?